# What's the best way to perform recurring task in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

So I have a simple personal finance app that needs to perform recurring expense on monthly basis (Automatically, without user action). What's the best way to do it?

EventKit seems not the best tools for it while NSTimer is limited on 50 - 100 milliseconds.

Thanks!

Comment: you wish to perform a task every once in a month.. ?

Comment: Yup. Example: Cable TV expense that will automatically recorded once in a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why couldn't you just check current date/time and run all pending tasks in different places of your application, for example when new view is displayed or `-applicationSignificantTimeChange:` is called? Do you really need to process your task both in background and with a millisecond-to-second precision?

I mean, you are periodically (by timer or just by user action) checking if your recurring tasks need to be executed, and then run and record them.

I was working on a money tracking app once in my career, and we had implemented recurring tasks in that way. It was easy, painless and no user complained.

Answer (score 0):

Apple allows recurring background tasks only for very few purposes: audio, location-updates, voip, newsstand-content, external-accessory.

You may check the correpsonding section in the [iOS programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20/).

I guess its quite tough to match your feature to one of the background modes.

Comment: Many other personal finance apps can perform recurring payment. So, I guess, it's lil'bit tricky?

Comment: So far I did not find an appropriate solution, using the VoIP feature enables background code execution with minimum interval of 10 minutes (not sure about the maximum interval). Do the personal finance apps you mentioned have to be running in the task bar in order to perform the recurring payment calculation?

Comment: Not sure (But, I think it's not). You can set a date which the expense will automatically recorded. The expense will not displayed (and calculated) on expense list until that date.

Comment: Let's assume you set this date to April 2nd and do not touch your phone from end of March until April 4th. When you (re-)start the app on April 4th I guess it recognizes that your date has been exceeded and performs some updates during (re-)start. But so far I don't think that the app executes code on April 2nd while beeing suspended in background. The -applicationSignificantTimeChange: notification, iHunter mentioned, is delayed until the user (re-)starts the app.

Comment: I have an idea, I'll check the recurring expense every-time the app perform didFinishLaunching or applicationWillEnterForeground, if there's a recurring expense date that match today's date or the date has been exceeded I will set the action. Will post update when its proven. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The best way is using [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object which can be set on specific date with your own repeat interval.

Comment: Tomasz is right, but the user has to push the notification each time in order to trigger any code execution. However, AFAIK there is no more convenient way to to this.